# Aurelia router, html only views, add some javascript?

Tags: aurelia

I have a child router in one of my views. This child router is used to allow people to navigate to different subviews. Now these subviews do not require any logic so using just a .html view with no js viewmodel works find. The this is that some of these subviews are quite long and if you navigate from one to the next then the scroll position stays at the same spot as in the previous page.

```
configureRouter(config, router) {

  config.map([
    { route: '', name: 'main', moduleId: 'main_view', nav: false, title: 'Main' },
    { route: 'sub_view_1', name: 'p1', moduleId: 'sub_view_1.html', nav: true },
    { route: 'sub_view_2', name: 'p1', moduleId: 'sub_view_2.html', nav: true },
    { route: 'sub_view_3', name: 'p2', moduleId: 'sub_view_3.html', nav: true },
    { route: 'sub_view_4', name: 'p3', moduleId: 'sub_view_4.html', nav: true },
    { route: 'sub_view_5', name: 'p4', moduleId: 'sub_view_5.html', nav: true },
    { route: 'sub_view_6', name: 'p5', moduleId: 'sub_view_6.html', nav: true } 
  ]);

  this.router = router;
}
```

A possible solution is to add a `script` tag with the following query to each subview:

```
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
```

However, that would be mixing js and html.

Another possible solution would be to create a viewmodel for each of the subviews. But this seems like a lot of work to just add one line of code.

Is there any other possible solution? Maybe have each subview reference the same viewmodel?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you are required to have a VM class for each page. It's annoying, but it is how it is for now. The class can be empty, though. It can be as simple as this:

```
export class EmptyVM { }
```

As far as code that you want to run when every view is rendered, I'd recommend hooking in a `postRender` hook to the router.

```
export class Page {
  configureRouter(config, router) {
    config.addPostRenderStep(ScrollToTopRenderStep);

    config.map([
      { route: '', name: 'main', moduleId: 'main_view', nav: false, title: 'Main' },
      { route: 'sub_view_1', name: 'p1', moduleId: 'sub_view_1', nav: true },
      //...
    ]);

    this.router = router;
   }
 }

 class ScrollToTopRenderStep {
   run(navigationInstruction, next) {
     $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found an interesting way of scrolling back to top without JQuery and without adding an extra VM class.

I assume you have an overflow container in each of your views (the element that have the actual scrollbar).
just add a `one-time` binding to that container for the `scrolltop` property, you will bind it to the `0` value, and your done.
this works because each time a new view will be loaded, aurelia will rebind this binding - causing the `scrollTop` property of that element to be `0`.

the only downsize is that you will not have a nice scrolling affect.

```
<template>
    <div scrolltop.one-time="0"> <!-- your overflow container -->
      a very big html fragment that causes scrolling<br>
      a very big html fragment that causes scrolling<br>
      ...
  </div>
</template>
```